# Office 2016 find activation date

Tags: ms-office

is there any known way to programmatically find the activation timestamp for Office 2016 (2013) Home and Business (Retail,OEM), if the product was activated online (not KMS!)

I don't mean the *installation* timestamp (which I could read from the control panel and installer registry), and not the license expiry date (displayed by the OSPP script), but simply the last date and time when the product was successfully registered/activated online.

A hint: may be gold or misleading: some people discussed how to programmatically read the activation key from an installed/activated machine. I remember that someone mentioned that this info had in older Office versions been stored in teh registry, but for newer versions it was stored in a file (cannot remember the name, unfortunately). One way I could guess is to read the file's timestamp, either creation time or last modification time), but alas, I cannot remember the file name.

Can anyone either provide the info where to read the activation timestamp, or help me what the activation file name and path is?

Thanks very much

Armin.

Answer (score 0):

I found, I think, a satisfactory solution, and want to share it with anyone running into he same issue. I cannot guarantee however, that this works in all possible scenarios, I found it working whan I do a first-time install of Office on a machine, but didn't check wether it works in a re-installation or repair scenario as well.

On my machines, the activation creates a file

"Tokens.dat"

in

c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform.

The file **creation** date (use dir "filename" **/TC**) will show exactly the product activation date and time.

Hope this helps anyone in the future

Armin.